# How to disable org-mode 9.4.4 from indenting

Tags: org-mode

After upgrading to org-mode 9.4.4 when I create a simple org file with a list (though it could be a heading) like below:

```
- test
```

And hit return, then it automatically indents. This doesn't make any sense because there is no hierarchy. How can I disable this?

Answer (score 1):

Set the variable `org-adapt-indentation` to `nil` by running the command `M-x set-variable`.

Comment: I have `org-adapt-indentation` set to `nil`, and it's still doing the behavior described. Per the [org-mode FAQ](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-faq.html#indentation) the correct solution appears to be to disable electric indent for org-mode with a mode hook.

Answer (score 0):

#### Why it does make sense:

plain list entry doesn't limit to single line. Below is legit list.

```
- In publishing and graphic design, Lorem ipsum is a
  placeholder text commonly used to demonstrate the
  visual form of a document or a typeface without
  relying on meaningful content.
```

#### How can I disable this?

Usually `C-j` and `RET`(or `C-m`) behave differently, one does indentation and the other
doesn't. You may check it up and consider exchanging its bindings. (In my emacs RET bind
to `org-return` and it doesn't indent by default)

Comment: I didn't see this as a counter-example to the question, as it shows the behavior of a long line, not a return. It does, indeed, make sense to me that a long line should wrap and be considered part of the "legit list." It does not make sense to me that a return should [usually/mostly/be assumed to] do the same.